# Cython: Proper way to declare an unsigned int

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Going through some source code in scikit-learn, I noticed in `tree.pxd`some of the following type declarations:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.npy_float32 DTYPE_t          # Type of X
ctypedef np.npy_float64 DOUBLE_t         # Type of y, sample_weight
ctypedef np.npy_intp SIZE_t              # Type for indices and counters
ctypedef np.npy_int32 INT32_t            # Signed 32 bit integer
ctypedef np.npy_uint32 UINT32_t          # Unsigned 32 bit integer
```

I know there is some discussion on the [Cython docs here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#automatic-type-conversion) about the difference between C types and cython types, but these seem to be types from numpy, and they aren't mentioned in the documentation.

I'm confused about what types I should be using. For indexes, should I be using `SIZE_t` as defined above, or `unsigned int`? Is it really necessary for these `ctypedef`s to exist?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987390/cython-why-when-is-it-preferable-to-use-py-ssize-t-for-indexing

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser. Your post let me do this `__init__.pxd` file: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L325

Answer (score 5):

According to this [**init**.pxd file](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L325) for cython's numpy, it seems that `unsigned int` is the same exact thing as `npy_uint32`.

On the other hand, `npy_intp` is the same thing as `Py_intptr_t`, according to [this line](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L30) of the file. And I'm pretty sure that means the size of pointers, which corresponds to the spacing between items in an array, etc.

I think based upon [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987390/cython-why-when-is-it-preferable-to-use-py-ssize-t-for-indexing?lq=1), without mention, `Py_intptr_t` is preferred, to accommodate between architecture differences. So to really nail down on architecture accommodation, `npy_intp` should be used.